# How to remove author from Social sharing links?

Tags: author, sharing

You see how it says By Terrance, I've tried everything to take it out. Nothing will do it. Any help would be appreciated. www.doseoftechnology.com

[image]

Comment: Remove "descr" from function

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your article in the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdoseoftechnology.com%2Fcharging-your-phone-in-seconds-and-the-future-of-batteries%2F) and it looks like it is still pulling in this meta tag `<meta name="author" content="terrance" />`. I'm assuming you deleted that from your site's `<head>` already as I am not seeing it in the source code for that article. Have you "fetched a new scrape" of the article yet? If not, you can fetch a new scrape by clicking the button as shown in the image below. You may have to repeat the scrape a few times to get Facebook's cache of your article cleared. [Here is the link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdoseoftechnology.com%2Fcharging-your-phone-in-seconds-and-the-future-of-batteries%2F) again to the facebook debugger for your article.

[image]